# If you toss 10 fair coins in how many ways can you obtain at least two tails?

Tags: combinatorics

$\binom{10}0 = 1 \rightarrow $ no tails

$\binom{10}1 = 10 \rightarrow $ one tail only

$2^{10} = 1024$

$1024-11 = 1013 $

> is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems good. Total possibilities - total with exactly zero tails - total with exactly one tail.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, with the usual interpretation of the problem. One could also say it is $9$. But the advantage of your count is that the ways are equally likely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what if the question asked a If you toss 10 fair coins in how many ways can you obtain at least one head and at least one tail?

Comment: That's  easier, $1022$. The only "bad" ones are all heads and all tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. # of possibilities that at least two tails would occur: $2^{10}-11$

Comment: @ kaka what if the question asked a If you toss 10 fair coins in how many ways can you obtain at least one head and at least one tail?

Comment: $2^{10}-2=1022$ or $\left[ \frac{2\times 10!}{1!9!}+\frac{2\times 10!}{2!8!}+\frac{2\times 10!}{3!7!}+\frac{2\times 10!}{4!6!}+\frac{10!}{5!5!} \right]=1022$